# Leaftletjs load XML and GeoJSON

Tags: leaflet, javascript, geojson, xml

I found below piece of code which loads GeoJSON from USGS then shows circle and set radius.
This works fine when tested.

```
(function () {
      
var FEED1 = 'http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';
      
var NOW = new Date();
      
var earthquakes = L.geoJson([], {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { 
          var props = feature.properties;
          layer.bindPopup('Dat: ' + props.time + '</br>' + 'Vr: ' + props.magtype + '</br>' + 'Ma: ' + props.mag + '</br>' + 'Du: ' + props.depth + ' km' + '</br>' + 'Iz: ' + props.source_catalog);
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          var color,
              mag,
              radius,
              weight;
          mag = feature.properties.mag;
          if (mag === null) {
            color = '#FF0000';
            radius = 2;
            weight = 0.7;
          } else {
            color = '#FF0000';
            radius = 2 * Math.max(mag, 1);
            weight = 0.7;
          }
          if (feature.properties.type === 'quarry blast') {
            color = '#FF00FF';
          }
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: color,
            radius: radius,
            weight: weight
          });
        }
      }).addTo(map);

      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.onload = function () {
        var results = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        earthquakes.addData(results);
      };
      xhr.open('GET', FEED1, true);
      xhr.send();
    })();
```

How can I based on above code load XML from http://webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=2021-05-29&minlatitude=42.12&maxlatitude=44.14&minlongitude=9.90&maxlongitude=14.47 and get circles and radius on maps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A working solution using an adapted version of https://github.com/usgs/quakeml-parser-js to deal with the XML (issues with parsing and unwanted "require")
I've also use `fetch` instead of the old `xhr`/`XMLHttpRequest` approach (cf https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
            crossorigin=""></script>
    <!-- Code mainly borrowed from https://github.com/usgs/quakeml-parser-js but done bad workarounds to avoid using "require"
      and made some code change to avoid some errors while parsing (was parsing only one event...) -->
    <script src="quakeml.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
          crossorigin=""/>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #map {
        /* configure the size of the map */
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      // initialize Leaflet
      var map = L.map('map').setView({lon: 0, lat: 0}, 2);

      // add the OpenStreetMap tiles
      L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
      }).addTo(map);

      // show the scale bar on the lower left corner
      L.control.scale().addTo(map);

      var FEED1 = 'https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson';
      var FEED2 = 'https://webservices.ingv.it/fdsnws/event/1/query?starttime=2021-05-29&minlatitude=42.12&maxlatitude=44.14&minlongitude=9.90&maxlongitude=14.47';
      var NOW = new Date();
      var earthquakes = L.geoJson([], {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) { 
          var props = feature.properties;
          layer.bindPopup('Dat: ' + props.time + '</br>' + 'Vr: ' + props.magtype + '</br>' + 'Ma: ' + props.mag + '</br>' + 'Du: ' + props.depth + ' km' + '</br>' + 'Iz: ' + props.source_catalog);
        },
        pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
          var color,
              mag,
              radius,
              weight;
          mag = feature.properties.mag;
          if (mag === null) {
            color = '#FF0000';
            radius = 2;
            weight = 0.7;
          } else {
            color = '#FF0000';
            radius = 2 * Math.max(mag, 1);
            weight = 0.7;
          }
          if (feature.properties.type === 'quarry blast') {
            color = '#FF00FF';
          }
          return L.circleMarker(latlng, {
            color: color,
            radius: radius,
            weight: weight
          });
        }
      }).addTo(map);
      
      fetch(FEED1, {
        method:'GET'
      })
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        earthquakes.addData(json);
      });

      fetch(FEED2, {
        method:'GET'
      })
      .then(r => r.text())
      .then(text => {
        // Volontarily forgot the var declaration for console debugging purpose in above variables
        // Should be added in real usage instead of demo purpose
        xml = (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(text, "text/xml");
        quakeObject = Quakeml({xml: xml});
        mags = quakeObject.getMagnitudes()
        geojson = {
          "type": "FeatureCollection",
          "features": quakeObject.getOrigins().map((el, i) => {
            return {
                "type": "Feature",
                "properties": {
                  // Need to reconciliate properties of both source (not same properties exactly, some already retrieved)
                  time: el[0].time.value,
                  depth: el[0].depth.value,
                  mag: Number(mags[i][0].mag.value),
                  magtype: mags[i][0].type
                },
                "geometry": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": [
                    Number(el[0].longitude.value),
                    Number(el[0].latitude.value)
                  ]
                }
              }
          })
        };
        earthquakes.addData(geojson);
      })


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Be aware you also need the `quakeml.js` file (a library file so not pasted here) Full source code https://gist.github.com/ThomasG77/220c74f4b10f7cac94fceecf9c09a313 including the `quakeml.js`.

See it in action at https://gist.githack.com/ThomasG77/220c74f4b10f7cac94fceecf9c09a313/raw/9682112b399df0b019a72697d57ede06d5b235fe/index.html

Comment: Thank you so so much. This works fine and I have adjusted few things for popup info.